# No whitespace using \listoffigures

Tags: table-of-contents

I have the following problem:
When using \listoffigures there is no white space after the second picture and the description of the picture, see:
[image] 
As you can see there is no white space between the number of the picture. 
I think the problem is here:

```
\let\default@listoffigures\listoffigures
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
    {
        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
        \default@listoffigures
    }
    \pagebreak
}
```

But I cant find it. Does anyone know where the problem is?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Could you create a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497) that shows the problem?  I'm not quite understanding your image.  Unless you're working in a different language, and what we're seeing is a cropped version of "Figure 14Eth...".

Comment: Hello, thanks @Teepeemm . I updated my question. Maybe that clarifies the confusion. Normally theres a whitespace between "Abbildung" and the Name of the Figure. But after figure 10 theres no white space anymore.

Comment: Hello, thanks @Mensch.  Normally I would create a MEW, but in this case I unfortunately don't know how to do it. Unfortunately, this piece of code is the only starting point I have